# Android Update Current Location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

So here is my method for getting the user saved location and then move camera to that location:

```
     private void updatePlaces(){

    locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
    double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();

    LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

    if(userMarker!=null) userMarker.remove();

    userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(lastLatLng)
    .title("You are here")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
    .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
    theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 3000, null);
    }
```

How can i modify this code in order to get the new position only once, compare and then get camera to it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand you question, if you run the method `updatePlaces()`  only ones it will `getLastKnownLocation` only once and updates the user marker only once. could you please be more explanatory on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the final result has to be like on viber `send location button`. so that map opens, finds the last known location, and then finds the actual location so that the user will not wait till the gps is working. Should i stat listening for updates and then stop them after 30 sec?  
`String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
// Or, use GPS location data:
// String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);`

Comment: it may change depending on the GPS signal strength and when you will receive a better location. you may want to look in to the Criteria (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html) class to understand how good/accurate the location update was and depending on that decide if you need more updates or not.